# Script to automatically execute multiple runs of a c++ program

Tags: c++, automation, execution

Consider a basic program - SumOf2Numbers.cpp. I can give 2 number as input through command line and it give the sum of the number.

I want to run this program with various inputs like,

```
./a.out 5 6
./a.out 123456 654321
./a.out -200 200
```

And the output would be,

```
5 + 6 = 11
-200 + 200 = 0 
123456+654321 = 777777
```

I want to automate this process of executing the c++ code and storing the output in a file. I am new to writing scripts. I would like to know how I can do this ? I believe I can do this by writing perl or bash scripts. Can someone guide me to a nice tutorial on this.

PS: I am sure there would be lot of online tutorials. But I am not sure how exactly I should perform the search.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done easily with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
(
  ./a.out 5 6
  ./a.out 123456 654321
  ./a.out -200 200
) > output.txt
```